# ¿Trasladar método de una Activity a una clase utilitaria? ¿Es posible? ¿Qué parámetros tendría que pasar?

Tags: android

Yo necesito utilizar un método que cambia los colores de fondo de la Toolbar y de la barra de estado.

La cuestión es que necesito usar ese método en varias `Activity`, por lo que he pensando trasladarlo a una clase `Utils`.

El problema es que no sé qué parámetros pasarle exactamente, ni cuál sería la mejor manera de hacerlo, ni si convendría hacerlo.

Este es el método en la `Activity` actual, el cual funciona.

```
private void setBarColor(int colorTiempo) {
    ActionBar ab = this.getSupportActionBar();

    switch (colorTiempo) {
        case 1:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_adviento)));
            break;
        case 2:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_navidad)));
            break;
        case 3:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma)));
            break;
        case 6:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco)));
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma));
            break;
        case 92:
            ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_rojo)));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Aquí yo manejo los siguientes elementos de la Activity actual:

- Su `ActionBar`
- El `Window` (ver `case 6`)
- Recursos de `colors.xml`

¿Si quiero pasar este método a mi clase `Utils`, cómo podría hacerlo, o sea, qué parámetros tendría que pasarle exactamente para que trabaje fuera de la `Activity` y al mismo tiempo cambie el estado de algunos elementos de la misma?

¿Es factible hacer esto sin riesgo?

Hice un intento más o menos así:

```
private void setBarColor(int colorTiempo, AppCompatActivity a) {
    ActionBar ab = a.getSupportActionBar();

    switch (colorTiempo) {
        case 1:
           ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_adviento)));
           a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma));
            break;
        case 2:
....
```

Pero no sé si sea lo mejor. Me da error en la parte de `ColorDrawable...`, sin duda tendría que pasarle una referencia a ese recurso.

En definitiva, quiero saber si convendría hacer esto para simplificar el código y cuál sería la mejor manera, sin caer en opiniones.

Gracias.

Comment: al recibir el contexto puedes obtener el recurso, ejemplo a.getResources().... en realidad comunmente se realiza como lo tratas de intentar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo clásico es crear una clase `Utilities` o `Utils` y agregar ahí métodos que usa la aplicación, que parámetros, sin duda el más importante es el contexto ya sea de la aplicación o de la Activity usado en el caso de generar un diálogo.

Al recibir el contexto puedes obtener el recurso y usar la clase `ColorDrawable` sin problema:

```
ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(/* a es el contexto */a.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_adviento)));
```

El método debe ser definido como `static`, este es un ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código y es precisamente como la idea que tienes:

```
public static void setBarColor(AppCompatActivity a, int colorTiempo) {
        ActionBar ab = a.getSupportActionBar();

        switch (colorTiempo) {
            case 1:
                ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRojo)));
                a.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(a.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRojo));
                break;
            case 2:
                ...
                ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oye, funciona de maravilla. ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Un placer ayudar @A.Cedano